# Dropdown selected change event fire on button Click event

Tags: asp.net

I have write the code in .Net. When I click the Buttun then fired below event. Please help how to do this.

```
protected void ddldesignation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Code.
}
```

Comment: if you have already "write the code" what is left to do? here's a guess tho - set autopostback=true on the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the button is in the page's form collection, you can use that as a condition to stop your drop down list event firing.

```
protected void ddldesignation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool runEventCode = true;
    foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
    {
        Control c = Page.FindControl(ctl);
        if (c is Button)
        {
            runEventCode = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (runEventCode)
    {
        //Event handler code here
    }
}
```